# How to Bind keyup event to jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i am trying to create jQuery plugin which needs to **trigger on keyup of input tag**.
But, somehow its not working :(

I've tried it so far:

**JS:**

```
$.fn.search_panel = function() {
    if($(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'input'){
        var input_str = $.trim($(this).val());
        console.log($(this));

        onkeyup = function(){
            console.log(input_str);
        }
    }
};
```

**Plugin Initialization**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').search_panel();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" />
```

From the above code, it only **console when page loads for the first time**, but after entering anything in **input box** it doesn't console.

Comment: Well it *should* trigger onkeyup anywhere on the page because your binding onto the `window` onkeyup event instead of the input's. Use `$(this).on("keyup")` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inadvertantly binding to the `window`'s `onkeyup` event. You should use `$(this).on` instead to bind to the individual keyup event on each input:

```js
$.fn.search_panel = function() {
    // Iterate all elements the selector applies to
    this.each(function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        // Can probably make this more obvious by using "is"
        if($input.is("input")){
            // Now bind to the keyup event of this individual input
            $input.on("keyup", function(){
                // Make sure to read the value in here, so you get the
                // updated value each time
                var input_str = $.trim($input.val());
                console.log(input_str);
            });
        }
    });
};
$('input').search_panel();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input><input><input><input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `keyup` event inside plugin and bind it to current input,

```
$.fn.search_panel = function () {
    if ($(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'input') {
         $(this).keyup(function () {
            var input_str = $.trim($(this).val());
            console.log($(this));
            console.log(input_str);
         });
    }  
};
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s11htnka/)**

Comment: You forgot to remove the other `onkeyup` assignment. Also, you can move `$(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase()` higher up the chain - no need to check that on every key press